# import socket io client in a angular 2 app

Tags: node.js, sockets, angular, socket.io

I tried to include socket io client into an angular 2 app and I got this error:

> zone.js:1805 GET
>   http://localhost:8080/node_modules/socket.io-client/socket.io.js 404
>   (Not Found) (index):26 ZoneAwareError {__zone_symbol__error: Error:
>   (SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading
>   http://localhost:8080/node_modules/socket.io-cli…,
>   __zone_symbol__stack: "(SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http:…0/app/protected/chat/chat.service/chat.service.js", originalErr:
>   ZoneAwareError}

the `package.json`looks like this:

```
{

},
"keywords": [],
"author": "",
"license": "MIT",
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~2.3.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~2.3.0",
    "@angular/core": "~2.3.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~2.3.0",
    "@angular/http": "~2.3.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~2.3.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.3.0",
    "@angular/router": "~3.3.0",
    "@angular/upgrade": "~2.2.0",

    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.2.4",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "ng2-webstorage": "^1.5.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.8",
    "rxjs": "5.0.1",
    "socket.io-client": "^1.7.2",
    "systemjs": "0.19.40",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.6"
},
"devDependencies": {

    "@types/core-js": "^0.9.34",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.45",
    "concurrently": "^3.0.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.2",
    "typescript": "^2.0.3"
},
"repository": {}
```

}

and the `systemjs.config.js` looks like this:

```
(function(global) {
System.config({
    paths: {
        // paths serve as alias
        'npm:': 'node_modules/'
    },
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    map: {
        // our app is within the app folder
        app: 'app',

        // angular bundles

        // other libraries
        "socket.io-client": 'npm:socket.io-client',
        'rxjs': 'npm:rxjs'


    },
```

> // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename
>   and/or no extension

```
    packages: {
        'ng2-webstorage': { main: 'bundles/core.umd.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
        "socket.io-client": { main: './socket.io.js' },
        app: {
            main: './main.js',
            defaultExtension: 'js'
        },
        rxjs: {
            defaultExtension: 'js'
        }
    }
});
})(this);
```

I used it like this:

```
import * as io from "socket.io-client";
this.socket = io.connect("http://localhost:8080");
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Were you able to resolve this? I am also getting same error.